# R installing the package Rcplex for window

Tags: r, installation

It have something problem,when I installing Rcplex.

```
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I"/include"    -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c Rcplex.c -o Rcplex.o
In file included from Rcplex.c:2:0:
Rcplex.h:4:27: fatal error: ilcplex/cplex.h: No such file or directory
#include <ilcplex/cplex.h>

compilation terminated.
make: *** [Rcplex.o] Error 1
Warning: 執行中命令 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="Rcplex.dll" OBJECTS="Rcplex.o Rcplex_QCP.o Rcplex_params.o Rcplex_utils.o"' 已有狀態 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rcplex'
* removing 'C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Rcplex'

 Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\user\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2HBKKW/downloaded_packages/Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("Rcplex") :installation of package ‘Rcplex’ had non-zero exit status
```

is that means my install location is not consistent with cplex ???

and I found out the package index say that the package is not available for Windows binaries 
so is the package cannot use for Windows?
I already install cplex. how to fix it? Please!!

Comment: Have you read the install [file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/INSTALL).  It looks like you need to configure it a bit: "Installation on Windows systems is done by using the provided
Makevars.win file in the src directory."

Comment: I already read this yet.should I create a file that name called Makevars.win? but what does "src directory" means?

Comment: The file (Makevars.win) they are referring to is in the `src` directory of the package `Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz`.  It looks like you need to change the `${CPLEX_DIR} ` to the location of the windows directory location.  Then repackage and install using `R CMD INSTALL
--no-multiarch Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz`

Comment: I follow your suggest until when I type
    "R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch Rcplex_0.3-3.tar.gz"
but it show error message
    "Error: unexpected symbol in "R CMD"
what's happen..?

Comment: You should run this command from the windows prompt: `cmd.exe`.  Or you could install within R by doing `install.packages(path_to_file, repos = NULL, type="source")`